# Parameters are being inadvertently placed in URL after routing

Tags: angular

Using Angular 5, I am using routing to navigate between pages / components. For a login component I am navigating to the Home component after signout. After navigation is complete, parameters are being passed into the URL that shouldn't be there.

This is my TS for `LoginComponent`:

```
.....
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  emailVal: string = '';
  pswdVal: string = '';

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  signout() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route })
    //Makes Home URL http://localhost:4200/?email=&password=
  }
```

This is my routing setup:

```
  const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: 'review/:id', component: ReviewComponent },
  { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'category/:id', component: CategoryComponent },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

At the end, do this rather then doing the same as you did on the line before:

```
    ...
     { path: '**',
       redirectTo: HomeComponent,
       pathMatch: 'full' }
    ];
```

This will default to home component, so any url pattern that is not specified in your routes will go to the home component. So you likely ought not write:

```
    this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route })
```

but just write something like:

```
    this.router.navigate(['/logout']) //or home to be explicit which you have no reason not to be.
```

If this still does not work, it must be something from this line:

```
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
```

in which case you ought to put more code explaining what occurs during this.

Comment: I was not able to use `redirectTo: HomeComponent` as this created a TypeScript error. I was able to change it to `redirectTo: 'home'`, however the parameters were still being placed in the URL. `this.afAuth.auth.signOut()` invokes AngularFire Auth's `signOut()` method for Firebase authentication.

Comment: Of course this is a duplicate, this.afAuth.auth.signOut(); is a promise! Here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41365528/angularfire-2-auth-logout-callback

Comment: This did not fix my issue.